# 'ColorResource' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context in GeneratedAssetSymbols

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, xcode15

I am trying to use extension ColorResource from GeneratedAssetSymbol.swift file

error says:
GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift:363:32 'ColorResource' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Below is the code:

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
@available(iOS 11.0, tvOS 11.0, *)
@available(watchOS, unavailable)
extension UIKit.UIColor {

    /// Initialize a `UIColor` with a color resource.
    convenience init(resource: ColorResource) { // This is where i am getting the error 
#if !os(watchOS)
        self.init(named: resource.name, in: resource.bundle, compatibleWith: nil)!
#else
        self.init()
#endif
    }

}
```

Does any one have any idea how can i solve this or have any options.
I am running the project in Xcode15 Beta (8).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a build that's failing to Archive because of ambiguous use in the Xcode generated file: 100s of lines similar to: `static var gr100: SwiftUI.Color { .init(.gr100) }`